# PayPal - IOS SDK - Live production env communications error

Tags: ios, paypal

We have implemented the IOS SDK (https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-iOS-SDK) into a Native IOS app that we are building -  All was working fine during initial tests (both Sandbox and production) - a payment for 10p in GBP worked without issue in the live production environment on Nov 5th.

Checked a production environment transaction again today as part of the apps final tests and although we can log in with a live PayPal account - the payment fails with an error stating -

```
  'Were sorry There was a problem communicating with the paypal servers.  Please try again.'
```

No Log errors that seem to be relevant, just these -

```
 2013-11-27 15:51:32.528 GetPTFit[2181:60b] nested push animation can result in corrupted navigation bar
 2013-11-27 15:51:32.893 GetPTFit[2181:60b] Finishing up a navigation transition in an unexpected state. Navigation Bar subview tree might get corrupted.
```

bizarre - has anyone experienced anything similar and know how to resolve!?

This is my pay method if any help -

```
- (IBAction)pay {

// Remove our last completed payment, just for demo purposes.
self.completedPayment = nil;

PayPalPayment *payment = [[PayPalPayment alloc] init];
payment.amount = [[NSDecimalNumber alloc] initWithString:self.shopObject.shopIPrice];
payment.currencyCode = @"GBP";
payment.shortDescription = self.shopObject.shopITitle;


if (!payment.processable) {
    // This particular payment will always be processable. If, for
    // example, the amount was negative or the shortDescription was
    // empty, this payment wouldn't be processable, and you'd want
    // to handle that here.
}

// Any customer identifier that you have will work here. Do NOT use a device- or
// hardware-based identifier.
NSString *customerId = @"GetPTFit";

// Set the environment:
// - For live charges, use PayPalEnvironmentProduction (default).
// - To use the PayPal sandbox, use PayPalEnvironmentSandbox.
// - For testing, use PayPalEnvironmentNoNetwork.



[PayPalPaymentViewController setEnvironment:PayPalEnvironmentProduction];

PayPalPaymentViewController *paymentViewController = [[PayPalPaymentViewController alloc] initWithClientId:kPayPalClientId
                                                                                             receiverEmail:kPayPalReceiverEmail
                                                                                                   payerId:customerId
                                                                                                   payment:payment
                                                                                               delegate:self];
paymentViewController.hideCreditCardButton = !self.acceptCreditCards;
// Setting the languageOrLocale property is optional.
//
// If you do not set languageOrLocale, then the PayPalPaymentViewController will present
// its user interface according to the device's current language setting.
//
// Setting languageOrLocale to a particular language (e.g., @"es" for Spanish) or
// locale (e.g., @"es_MX" for Mexican Spanish) forces the PayPalPaymentViewController
// to use that language/locale.
//
// For full details, including a list of available languages and locales, see PayPalPaymentViewController.h.
paymentViewController.languageOrLocale = @"en";

[self presentViewController:paymentViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dave from PayPal here.

Please see my response in [the issue that you raised at our github repo](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-iOS-SDK/issues/63). Feel free to respond in turn over there, or else here on StackOverflow if you prefer.

Comment: Hi Dave - Thanks for the comment - i've just updated the repo log - I feel it could be due to an invalid debit card on our test account - in which case the error didnt make sense - but it explained the issue - ive tested twice today and both worked fine..